# how to launch URL link in android emulator browser from windows

Tags: android, maven, js-test-driver

I have question. I want to automate testing in android browser.

My requirements:

I have `JS Test Driver` maven project which needs to be tested in android browser.

So what I want to do is

in maven `pom.xml` file instead of pointing to chrome as

```
<browser.command>C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe</browser.command>
```

Create `bat file` which will run command that launch URL link in android emulator browser  and point it to that `bat file`.

My problem is I don't know what command to write that will lunch particular URL in android emulator browser from command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your onClick method, use 
**Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
      .parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the `adb shell` tool in combination with the `am` command, you should be able to launch the browser on your Android device, and point it to an url of choice.

Something like (don't have a device with me at the moment, so cannot test):

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://your.url.here"
```

Put that in your bat-file and run it. It should automatically find a connected device. If you would also like to wait for a device to become available, check the `adb` documentation: this can also be done.

Comment: This works fine. Just a heads up to others who might have issues getting it working. I just ran into an issue when trying the above command in Terminal on Mac OSx because the quotation marks `"` had somehow got mangled into the fancy quotation marks `“` and `”`, causing an `Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent` error message.